# move file that is uploaded to another pc/ ip address

Tags: php, apache, file-upload, upload

I just wanna ask if its possible to make directory and store the uploaded file in it to a shared folder from another pc using mkdir and move_uploaded_file. I tried doing it locally it works fine but when i try this code

```
if($_REQUEST['submit']){
    $app_name = $_POST['name'];
    $desc = $_POST['description'];
    $file_url = "192.168.3.34/testupload/files/$app_name/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $photo_loc = "192.168.3.34/testupload/images/$app_name/" . $_FILES["photo"]["name"];
    $select = $_POST['select'];
    $date = date('m/d/y h:i:s A');

    mkdir("192.168.3.34/testupload/files/$app_name/");
    mkdir("192.168.3.34/testupload/images/$app_name/");
    /* some codes here  that is working */

    if($file != "" ){
        if (file_exists("..192.168.3.34/testupload/files/$app_name/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]) && file_exists("..192.168.3.34/testupload/images/$app_name/" . $_FILES["photo"]["name"])) {
            die("File Exists");
        }
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
            "192.168.3.34/testupload/files/$app_name/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);


        if($photo_url != "") {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"],
                "192.168.3.34/testupload/images/$app_name/" . $_FILES["photo"]["name"]);

        }
        $name = escape($_REQUEST['name']);
        $description = escape($_REQUEST['description']);
        //$query = "INSERT into files (name, description,file_name,photo_url,date_uploaded) values ('{$name}', '{$description}','{$file}', '{$photo_url}', now() )";
        //mysql_query($query) or die("Error in Query" . mysql_error());

        //commit();
        //redirect("manage.php");

        $file_loc = "192.168.3.34/testupload/files/$app_name/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        $photo_loc = "192.168.3.34/testupload/images/$app_name/" . $_FILES["photo"]["name"];
    }
}else{
    set_error("File not Found");
    //redirect('manage.php');
}
```

i tried to change the "/" in "\" and still getting this error

> Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\atts_update\upload.php on line 12
>
> Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\atts_update\upload.php on line 13
>
> Warning:
>   move_uploaded_file(192.168.3.34/testupload/files/1111111111111/sss.txt)
>   [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\atts_update\upload.php on line 71
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to
>   move 'C:\xampp\tmp\php610B.tmp' to
>   '192.168.3.34/testupload/files/1111111111111/sss.txt' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\atts_update\upload.php on line 71
>
> Warning:
>   move_uploaded_file(192.168.3.34/testupload/images/1111111111111/Picture-in-a-picture4aaa.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\atts_update\upload.php on line 76
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to
>   move 'C:\xampp\tmp\php611C.tmp' to
>   '192.168.3.34/testupload/images/1111111111111/Picture-in-a-picture4aaa.jpg' in C:\xampp\htdocs\atts_update\upload.php on line 76

Comment: I've tried this before, and ending up using FTP  commands. I wonder if people have better ideas ^^ (Also, right now you're referring to a local path with an IP address as folder name, thats why XAMPP won't get this)

Comment: You can mount folder from other PC to your and copy file without any special things. Just like copy file to another directory.

Comment: I've accomplished this task using [ssh2_scp_send](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-scp-send.php). However, this may require some server configuration for non existent packages.

Comment: Hi xyv can you share me how did you use FTP commands? And  what are the default credentials of a windows system. Thanks!

Comment: @Bierc What you need is to enable FTP service to the other computer and an account that is setup to access that folder. Once that is set up you can use [PHP FTP commands](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php) to upload your files (Using the FTP user's credentials you just made). However, Vladimir Gilevich Idea is pretty decent too! Read that one as well c: I've used this for backup storing and it works quite well... just some right issues that might need some attentions. give it a shot.

Comment: One other possible solution can be to use curl to send the files to å script on the other server. But then you would have to write two file upload scripts basicly :p